# Marsden and Tromba Vector Calculus Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm reading the chain rule proof from the vector calculus supplement to Marsden and Tromba. As part of the proof, to a supplementary theorem, they say, choose $\epsilon = 1$. I have attached the image.

I am confused here because I thought in $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions, you could only choose $\delta > 0$, and that your proof must work for all $\epsilon$.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The authors are not doing an epsilon-delta proof here, at least not in the portion shown in the image you posted. They have assumed that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. The definition of differentiability then says that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that some condition is satisfied. So in particular, for $\varepsilon = 1$, there is some $\delta_1>0$ such that the inequality at the bottom of the image holds.